# Cannot retrieve the integer getHeight()

Tags: java, android

I have created a `Layout` 'layout' programmatically, then I created a `TextView` in the same layout to display the `layout` `height`, there are no other methods or anything else in the class. Unfortunately the app closes, and I can't identify why.

```
LinearLayout layout =new LinearLayout(this);
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        layout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lparams.setMargins(0, 10, 0, 10);
        lparams.gravity= Gravity.CENTER;


        TextView fimText = new TextView(this);
        fimText.setLayoutParams(lparams);
        fimText.setText(layout.getHeight());
        layout.addView(fimText, lparams);
        setContentView(layout);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your LinearLayout needs to be added to a container before you can call getHeight on it. Also, getHeight returns an int so you need to convert it to a String.

Try this:

```
LinearLayout layout =new LinearLayout(this);
layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
layout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,     LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lparams.setMargins(0, 10, 0, 10);
lparams.gravity= Gravity.CENTER;

setContentView(layout);

TextView fimText = new TextView(this);
fimText.setLayoutParams(lparams);
fimText.setText(String.valueOf(layout.getHeight()));
layout.addView(fimText, lparams);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because `layout.getHeight()` will not return an `CharSequence` value. Add `.toString()` or `""+` to it.